# Error getting a userToken for Apple Music SDK with JWT

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, apple-music, apple-musickit

I'm trying unsuccessfully to get a userToken for Apple Music SDK using the developerToken from JWT.  I've used pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator and I could get a valid and static userToken. But apple recommend to make dynamic, so I'm trying to use JWT again.

Someone can tell me please what's wrong with my code? Thank you

```
func fetchDeveloperToken() -> String? {
   func fetchDeveloperToken() -> String? {
    let iat = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    let days = TimeInterval(24*60*60*120) //120 days
    let exp = TimeInterval(iat + days)
    let kid = "TBESJXXXXX"
    let iss = "KQ6Z6XXXXX"
    let alg = "ES256"
    let secret = "MIGTAgEAMBMGByqEU7ZHQsoVfmKCCxS5W6BnCgCgYIKoZIzj0AAQcggNoN7dTkNG/8timkkf+Z2toogAqN41YgOXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXsecretkey"
    let header:[AnyHashable:Any] = ["alg":alg, "kid":kid]
    let payload:[AnyHashable:Any] = ["iss": iss,
                                     "iat": iat,
                                     "exp": exp]
    let algorithm256 = JWTAlgorithmHS256()
    return JWT.encodePayload(payload, withSecret: secret, withHeaders: header, algorithm: algorithm256)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple requires you to use the ES256 algorithm, not HS256, I ran into the same issue too. The JWT libray that you're using doesn't support ES256 as you can see [here](https://jwt.io/). The only other library on iOS that is listed that supports it is [this one](https://github.com/vapor/jwt)

Comment: Well with this code above, I can generate a string, where running the command at terminal:   curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [developer token]' "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340"   I can get valid connection with api.music.apple.com and I can make my app to work. But. is a static string, which apple does not recommend...and has an fixed expiration date. :(

Comment: @Fri3ndlyGerman But how did you add this lib in iOS? This uses Swift Package Manager and :/

Comment: Just wanted to let you and others coming along here know: The information shown at https://jwt.io/ seems to be wrong. It says Vapor/JWT would support ES256 but it apparently does not: See this Issue here https://github.com/vapor/jwt/issues/92

Comment: Nowadays there are at least two pure Swift libraries that support ES256: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-JWT.git and https://github.com/klaas/CupertinoJWT